# .gitlab-ci.yml - wordpress service wait for db

Tags: wordpress, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I want to do some automatic testing with WordPress in GitLab CI.

```
test:
  image: alpine
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
  services:
    - alias: db
      name: mysql:5.7
    - alias: wp
      name: wordpress:4.7-apache
  variables:
    WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
    WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
    WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
    WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
    MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
    MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
  script:
    - echo "hi"
```

At the moment it doesnt work, because the WP container directly starts setup, while the DB still is setting up.

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22
```

Can I add some delay somehow? GitLab doesn't offer that and also there is no environment variable the WP container, right?

**Update 2021-03-29**: GitLab issue created:  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/326199

Comment: It seems like a gitlab issue. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/24197 many similar discussions are there. Just a workaround , try a docker-compose file and use shell based gitlab runner.

Comment: Thanks @SachithMuhandiram, I saw this also. I think there is a huge backside. So before  I switch to that, I would put up an own wordpress image using wait-for-it.sh to start the setup once DB is available... Hopefully there's a better solution

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, it may be useful for anyone, as gitlab is not focused on this issue (seems to be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could have just read the docs. Just define `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1` in variables and the containers can talk to each other, see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/326199#note_794577385

Comment: Apologies. I First read this as someone telling someone else that they could have just read the docs.